# How to display linear day ticks on x time-axe in Chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I have dataset width random time moments and I'd like to display round dates on x axe like

```
|   |   |   |   |
12  13  14  15  16
oct oct oct oct oct
```

Looks like time.round iss the proper option, but it not works, my code

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: chart_labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Время доступа',
            data: chart_values,
            borderColor: ["#03A9F5"],
            borderWidth: 1,
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: "#03A9F522",
            pointRadius: 1,         
            pointHoverRadius: 5,            
        }]
    },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
    },    
    tension: 0.4,
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        'time.round': 'day',
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          stacked: true,
          text: 'Секунды',
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

And ticks go by 3 hours: 5pm 8pm 11pm...

**Edited**

**time: {round: 'day'}** is not a correct parameter, it moves dots to the beginning of a day, when I need to keep dots where they are but draw ticks on the begining of the days.
https://jsfiddle.net/7y2L9ueq/

Comment: I think the config is not correct. 'time.round' sounds not correct, try using time: { round: 'day'}. Also the 'y' scale sounds not correct because you added stacked and beginAtZero options in the title, but they should stay at upper level.

Comment: Yes, you wrote right syntax for round.day, but it makes absolutly another thing, I edited the question since it relates it's essence.

Comment: I think you don't need round: 'day but unit: 'day'. trying with unit: 'day' sounds work as you want.

Comment: Super! It is. You'd better write the answer and I mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using `round` option in the time.
For what you need, you should use `unit` option, which is defining the time unit on the axis.

```
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day' // <-- to use
        }
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          stacked: true,
          text: 'Секунды',
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
```